I can't access internet anymore after uninstalling pihole from my ubuntu server

I can still ssh to the server within local network.
I can't ping google.com or 8.8.8.8.
Here is the wireless-info script result:

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/63t9bN7Dc9/




How did you uninstall it? Did you do what it says in the docs: https://docs.pi-hole.net/main/uninstall/

Yes, and I selected remove all dependencies during the uninstallation process.

Did you modify your router settings to use the pihole as the DNS source? If so, did you revert this?

Yes, I did. I reverted the settings to AUTO after uninstalling.
